# Open garmin img file or convert to a shape file

Tags: image, gis, geospatial, garmin

I have a garmin img file which has digital elevation model for Nigeria which I would like to have as a shape file. Is there a way to do this which does not involved money. I am working as a volunteer on a project.

I have tried a number of options like qgis (to which I am a newbie) but I have not been successful.

Comment: You should state more precisely what you like the result to be. Contour lines?